# HttpHandler for WMV Files

Tags: asp.net

I have created a HttpHandler for WMV files. I have also registered it in the web.config. But for some reason it never fires. Let me explain the scenario:

I have linked to the videos on a website using the anchor tag. When you click the link the wmv file is run in windows media player. Now, I want that instead of link a media player should up right on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the video to play inside your web page you will need to embed a player capable of playing WMVs.  A good candidate for this is the [ASP.NET MediaPlayer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838173(VS.95).aspx), which makes it easy for you to embed a Silverlight based Media Player in any ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS (Internet Information Services) you should map the .WMV-extension to the ASP.NET parser.

More information here: http://www.zorched.net/2006/01/20/aspnet-web-application-without-aspx-extension/

Comment: OK, it looks like you have changed your question to something different :) My answer no longer applies i guess.